# ManyToOne Unidirectional Disable Constraint

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, constraints, many-to-one

I have following unidirectional ManyToOne relation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Child")
public class Child {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Parent parent; 
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent{
    @Id
    private Integer id;
}
```

When I am trying to delete parent Entity from database I have constraint violation.

> ORA-02292: integrity constraint violated - child record found

What I need is that parent Entity is deleted even if it has children, but children Entity should stay.

How do I change this relation?

Answer (score 1):

You can't with JPA if using a relationship.  Making it a ManyToOne indicates that a value in the foreign key field will exist in the Parent table.  JPA will not be able to distinguish between a null fk value and there being a fk value that just doesn't have an associated row in the Parent table.

If it really must be done (and it shouldn't IMO), you would need to map the Integer foreign key value in Child with a basic mapping instead of the ManyToOne. This allows it to be set independently of there being an existing Parent entity - null means null, a value means a value.  You can then query for the associated Parent entity if the entity itself is needed.

Comment: @Basic.  It's the default mapping for non entity types

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an optional=true parameter on the ManyToOne would help?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Child")
public class Child {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
    private Parent parent; 
}
```

I'm assuming you create the schema straight from Hibernate. The goal is to have the foreign key field nullable in the database.

Comment: It is optional by default according to documentation

Comment: Ah yes, good point - and this would not help you when deleting the parent, in any case. Would it be acceptable though to have a bi-directional relationship (a OneToMany collection on Parent side), so that you could set the parent of each child to null explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it can be done.

```
@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "none"))
```

It's only logical to specify a foreign key as lacking referential integrity constraint when you are describing the table that *contains* this foreign key column.

Surely it's not a best practice to remove the referential integrity constraints in your presistence layer when you are developing some OLTP system; but for **data warehouse**-alike solutions (first-load-data-then-check-it-as-a-whole) this may be the correct approach.